# What is the best and optimized way to fetch paginated results from a very large Mongo collection without any search criteria

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I am relatively new to MongoDB and want to fetch paginated results (without any search criteria) from a large collection (>650k documents). Right now I am using -

`db.myCollection.find().skip(skip).limit(limit)`

However the query is pretty slow as it takes about 12-15 secs for execution. My two major concerns are -

1. Faster execution time
2. Data transferred from the Mongo server to the backend server should be just the limited documents and not the complete collection.

I also ran executionStats with this query and here are the results -

```
{ explainVersion: '1',
  queryPlanner: 
   { namespace: 'db.myCollection',
     indexFilterSet: false,
     parsedQuery: {},
     queryHash: '17830885',
     planCacheKey: '17830885',
     maxIndexedOrSolutionsReached: false,
     maxIndexedAndSolutionsReached: false,
     maxScansToExplodeReached: false,
     winningPlan: 
      { stage: 'SKIP',
        skipAmount: 0,
        inputStage: { stage: 'COLLSCAN', direction: 'forward' } },
     rejectedPlans: [] },
  executionStats: 
   { executionSuccess: true,
     nReturned: 652376,
     executionTimeMillis: 13389,
     totalKeysExamined: 0,
     totalDocsExamined: 652396,
     executionStages: 
      { stage: 'SKIP',
        nReturned: 652376,
        executionTimeMillisEstimate: 10180,
        works: 652398,
        advanced: 652376,
        needTime: 21,
        needYield: 0,
        saveState: 994,
        restoreState: 994,
        isEOF: 1,
        skipAmount: 0,
        inputStage: 
         { stage: 'COLLSCAN',
           nReturned: 652396,
           executionTimeMillisEstimate: 10173,
           works: 652398,
           advanced: 652396,
           needTime: 1,
           needYield: 0,
           saveState: 994,
           restoreState: 994,
           isEOF: 1,
           direction: 'forward',
           docsExamined: 652396 } } },
  command: 
   { find: 'myCollection',
     filter: {},
     skip: 20,
     limit: 0,
     '$db': 'db' }
```

Comment: there is a library [mongo-pagination](https://github.com/mrbontor/mongo-pagination) using native driver Nodejs. maybe you can take some references for it

Comment: You didn't actually limit any data in that explain plan. What happens if you use a nonzero number? Also, will you always be reading the pages sequentially? Finally, skipping and limiting without requesting a (unique) sort may result in missing or duplicated results